# MSVC won't perform a user-defined implicit conversion to std::nullptr_t when invoking operator==

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

Consider the following piece of code:

```cpp
struct X { operator std::nullptr_t() const { return nullptr; } };
X x;
assert(x == nullptr);
```

As far as I can tell, it should work because `X` is implicitly convertible to `std::nullptr_t` and hence `operator==` should perform that implicit conversion to the left argument. This seems to be what happens in GCC and Clang, which happily accept the code. [CppInsights](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPGNhc3NlcnQ+CiNpbmNsdWRlIDxjc3RkZGVmPgoKaW50IG1haW4oKSB7CiAgICBzdHJ1Y3QgWCB7IG9wZXJhdG9yIHN0ZDo6bnVsbHB0cl90KCkgY29uc3QgeyByZXR1cm4gbnVsbHB0cjsgfSB9OwogICAgWCB4OwogICAgYXNzZXJ0KHggPT0gbnVsbHB0cik7Cn0K&insightsOptions=cpp20&std=cpp20&rev=1.0) seems to confirm that the implicit conversion indeed takes place as expected.

However, this code fails to compile in MSVC with the following error ([Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/KT76aErEG))

> error C2676: binary '==': 'main::X' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Is this code invalid, implementation specific behavior, or is MSVC wrong for rejecting it?

Comment: With the latest VC2019 I get the following error instead: C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'nullptr' ...

Comment: I've tested some more compilers and found some more data points. The code fails in GCC 10 and below with a similar error, but starts working in GCC 11 and above. However, it seems to work on every version of Clang as far back as Godbolt goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVC is wrong in rejecting the code since the program is well formed as the implicit conversion via the *conversion operator* can be done for the check `x == nullptr`.

A bug report for the same has been submitted [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-rejects-valid-code-involving-conver/10099194).

Comment: But, as I said in my comment, a local (real) installation of VS 2019 compiles the linked code without a problem. M/S will likely reject/discard that bug report unless you can send them a packaged repro from an actual instance of their software.

Comment: @AdrianMole Unfortunately I can't test the code locally and am only able to use godbolt for now. If the program can indeed be compiled without any problem locally(as you've said by testing it) then it is a problem with msvc's backend(or something else) in compiler explorer. Recently there has been a lot of compiler explorer bugs(mostly ui) three of which i have reported in compiler explorer's github repo and were confirmed to be compiler explorer bugs.

Comment: Never mind - I was compiling in Release mode, where `assert` is defined as a nothing-operation. Adding `#undef NDEBUG` makes the issue reproducible.

Comment: @AdrianMole I see!